# remove the local timezone from a date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I was wondering if I can remove the timezone from the date using javascript? I get the datetime on a json format, now I want to set it back but it returns more info of what I actually want/need.

What I have now is:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1432851021000);
document.write(d);
```

and the output is something like this:

```
Thu May 28 2015 16:10:21 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

Id like to show only until the hour, and remove GMT-0600 (CST).

I know javascript takes that depending on the current user's timezone, which is a problem, because the information could be saved on different countries.

I am trying to avoid to create the format using something like:

```
d.date() + "/" + d.month()...etc
```

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you use momentjs ? http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe `d.toDateString()` will output the format you're looking for.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1432851021000);
d.toDateString(); // outputs to "Thu May 28 2015"
d.toGMTString(); //outputs to "Thu, 28 May 2015 22:10:21 GMT"
```

Or even `d.toLocaleString()`
"5/28/2015, 6:10:21 PM"

There are lots of methods available to [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: `d.toLocaleString()` outputs to `"5/28/2015, 6:10:21 PM"`

Comment: Sorry i guess what you're looking for is `d.toGMTString();`

Comment: toLocateString works great, is there any way to specify the format? like DD-MM-YY ?

Comment: toLocaleString does accept different options for formatting. I'd review that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). This will output what you want though `d.toLocaleString("en-GB");`

Comment: Ah! thank you .toDateString did it for me. I had to replace the dashes with slashes from the HTML5 datepicker, but what me worry.  var d = new Date($('#Dances_Moderated_SingleDate').val().replace(/-/g, '\/'));  retVal= d.toDateString();

Answer (score 13):

Using moment

```
moment().utcOffset(0, true).format()
```

From Javascript Date

```
var date = new Date();
Tue Sep 06 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200

var isoDate = date.toISOString()
'2021-09-05T22:00:00.000Z'

var clearUTCDate = moment(date).utcOffset(0, true).format() 
'2021-09-06T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 12):

Since the part you want will always has fixed length you can use:

```
d.toString().slice(0, 24)
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/g2hp551L/)

Comment: thanks, but what would happen if someone has another timezone that is not GMT? or is -12?

Comment: So what's the desired output if the timezone is different? Do you want to convert the time to a specific timezone? Or show it if some conditions met? Otherwise slice will just remove the last timezone bit.

Answer (score 2):

with momentjs

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1432851021000);

var newdate = moment(d);

alert(newdate.format("MMM DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss "));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vynvepak/

Answer (score 1):

Using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html), the sample code below takes the current date and time, making it time zone agnostic in an [ISO Standard Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```js
const { DateTime, ToISOTimeOptions } = window.luxon;
const currentDate = new Date();

// Unspecified timezone.
console.log(
  DateTime.fromJSDate(currentDate)
    .toISO(
          {includeOffset:false} // ToISOTimeOptions
    )
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.0.2/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 options:
1. use split function: d.split('GMT'). this gives you an array.
2. get the usual js data functions like getHour and getFullYear and so on to format the result as you prefer.

Comment: thanks, 2nd options is a little bit nasty... specially since I have to check if day is minor 10 and then add a 0 to have it in proper format 01,02 , same with months, adding 1 because it returns 0-11 . Is GMT a default? or it depends on the configuration of the computer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = d.toDateString().length;
var result = d.toDateString() + d.toString().substring(x,x+9);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(myUnixTimestamp*1000);
var prettyDate = date.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created simple js function to remove timezone part from datetime string. It which will give output like

- 2019-07-27T19:00:00.000-0700 => 2019-07-27T19:00:00.000
- 2019-09-17T19:00:00.000+0100 => 2019-09-17T19:00:00.000

```js
function removeTimeZonePart(dateString) {
            
             let finalDate = '';
            
             if (dateString.split('+').length > 1) {
                 let b = dateString.split('+');
            
                 finalDate = b[0];
             } else {
                 let b = dateString.split('-');
            
                  if (b.length > 1) {
                   b.pop();
                   finalDate = b.join('-');
                 }
             }

             return finalDate;

}

alert(removeTimeZonePart('2019-07-27T19:00:00.000-0700'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 ways -**

**1. .toLocaleString()**
Will give you date time in this format -
'24/11/2021, 20:19:36'

but there's a caveat, you cannot parse this date-

```
const myDate = new Date('24/11/2021, 20:19:36')
=> Invalid Date
```

*If you want to be able to parse the date again, and also remove the timezone, use the 2nd method*

**2. .split("GMT")[0]**

Input:
new Date()
Wed Nov 24 2021 20:23:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Output:

```
"Wed Nov 24 2021 20:25:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".split('GMT')[0]
'Wed Nov 24 2021 20:25:17 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex arrived to the party

```js
// for ISO Datetime strings only

const rmvTZOffset = str => str.replace(/[+-]\d\d:\d\d$/, '')

console.log(rmvTZOffset('2023-02-22T10:18:17+00:00'))
console.log(rmvTZOffset('2024-02-22T10:18:17.7543-02:30'))

const zone = 'Europe/Lisbon'
fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/' + zone)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => {
    console.log(rmvTZOffset(r.datetime))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

for example we have date like:

```
const dateWithTimeZone = '2010-02-10T19:30:00.000Z'
```

compact solution is formatted to UTC and remove GMT from it. At the end we'll have date time without time zone:

```
const dateWithoutTimeZone = new Date(date).toUTCString().replace(' GMT', '')
```

*output: `'Wed, 10 Feb 2010 19:30:00'`*

Answer (score -1):

I feel there is a better yet simpler solution!

1. Extract the Day, Month & Year from your "Date Variable".

   - var day = d.getDate(); //to get the day
   - var month = d.getMonth(); // to get the month
   - var year = d.getYear(); // to get the year
2. Now just assign a new variable like

   - var newDate = day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year; //Note, we are doing (month+1) because in Javascript the month varibale runs from {0-11} (0: Jan , 1:Feb,2: Mar, 4: Apr.... 11:Dec)

And there you have it, your customized date without timezone is ready!

Comment: `getYear()` is deprecated and doesn't actually return the full year. I think `getFullYear()` is what you'd want

Comment: No bro take a look at my code snippet

var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getYear();
   var dT = new Date;
   var FulldT =new Date;
 dT = day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year;
    FulldT = dT.setFullYear(year,month,day);
    Logger.log(dT);
    Logger.log(FulldT);

Output: 
1>. 7/10/2019
2>.Mon Oct 07 23:08:21 GMT+05:30 2019

By using FullYear you again introduce the timezone.