# Strip the timezone from a date string and convert into Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

Before asking this question on this thread I checked out this possible duplicate: [remove the local timezone from a date in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535691/remove-the-local-timezone-from-a-date-in-javascript)

In my case I'm not getting the date in milliseconds when I do this, which results in the error "Invalid date":

```
// this is the date format I get as response from server
new Date("2018-09-17 14:02:09 +0530 IST")
```

Hence I cannot use the `toLocaleString()` on the date. I unfortunately also cannot use moment.js on my current project, as I would need permission to include external libraries.

I know there can be ways using the split or regex, but they I feel get too restricted to a certain use-case.

Is there a way I can convert `"2018-09-17 14:02:09 +0530 IST"` into `"2018-09-17 14:02:09"` or simply it could result into a readable date string?

Comment: I tried Date.parse("2018-09-17 14:02:09 +0530 IST") and it returns NaN

Comment: ^ because that's a non-standard date string

Comment: thanks all for the suggestions, I have it working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the date to GMT format. I would suggest that you reformat the string into `"2018-09-17 14:02:09 GMT+0530"` instead of `"2018-09-17 14:02:09 +0530 IST"`. I feel the string should be easily manipulated by using slice since the index of where the timezone is in the string would remain the same regardless of given time.

```js
let response = "2018-09-17 14:02:09 +0530 IST";
let dateStr = response.slice(0,20);
dateStr += "GMT+0530";
```

This should reformat the string into valid date input.