# format date object to string without changing the hour

Tags: javascript, date

So I'm having problem converting my date to this format:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss
```

my front end is retrieving the date from the date stored in the database but somehow when I convert it it's changing the hours. The date is:

```
2022-11-16T15:00:00.000Z
```

And I have tried:

```
const date = moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:ss")
```

it returned:

```
16/11/2022 12:11:00
```

How can I achieve just:

```
16/11/2022 15:00:00
```

Comment: In which format are you receiving the date? As a string?

Comment: Its Date format

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the mistakes you are making is using `HH:MM:ss`.
The MM is used for months and not for minutes. The correct syntax for this would be `HH:mm:ss`. See https://momentjs.com/ for reference. This explains why the minutes in your parsed date are wrong.

The hours being wrong could be an issue with the timezone. See here:
[https://www.alex-arriaga.com/how-to-set-moment-js-timezone-when-creating-a-date/#:~:text=Since%20Moment.,take%20the%20current%20user's%20timezone](https://www.alex-arriaga.com/how-to-set-moment-js-timezone-when-creating-a-date/#:%7E:text=Since%20Moment.,take%20the%20current%20user%27s%20timezone).

I have tried to reproduce this here https://jsfiddle.net/u70po41v/1/

Comment: Do you have any ideia why its subtracting to 12?? I changed it to mm and it worked for the minutes

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with the timezone. You could convert the date to a string and remove the 'Z' at the back of it and then parse it with momentjs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535691/remove-the-local-timezone-from-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: You could also try moment(date).utc(true).format(“DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss”)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a usual date function

```
const formatDate = date.toLocaleString()
// => DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:ss
```

Comment: Dont work because it subtracts the hours from 15 to 12

Comment: I think you may have a problem related to your utc. Is the date you're receiving from another country, or at least a place with different hours ?